# Chabad Chazzanus Recordings

Tags: product-recommendation, chabad, chazzan-prayer-leader, nusach-ari, recording

Is there a place online where I can find recordings of Chabad chazzanus (i.e. the tunes a Chabad chazzan would use for Hodu, Shemoneh Esrei, etc.)? The recordings should preferably be free online. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK there's no free recordings out there, but here's what I have found:

1. [Davening with the Rebbe](https://vimeo.com/18771198) - a recording of the Lubavitcher Rebbe davening shacharis on a weekday. Generally speaking, Chabad chassidim will use the same tune.
2. [Yossi Rutman](http://www.rutmanmusic.com/) has put out a CD with the Chabad nusach for the *Yamim Nora'im*, available on his [website](http://www.rutmanmusic.com/cd.html) and on [Kehot Online](http://store.kehotonline.com/prodinfo.asp?number=CD-CHABN).

Comment: The recordings of the Rebbe davening are as good a source as any for the weekday tunes, sure that is what the majority of Chassidim use. However, I came across quite a number of (especially younger) Chassidim who use a different tune, one which I personally disfavor.  Were your asking for Shabbat and Yom Tov tunes as well? Since the latter can have a huge variety of versions, often with subtle differences.

Comment: @Ysiegel I think you meant to ask that question to the OP, not to me.

Comment: Interesting, in the recording of the Rebbe davening he clearly says the ending of the bracha _gaal yisroel_ out loud. In my experience, Chabad communities nowadays always finish that bracha silently.

Comment: @Daniel In my experience, it has been said out loud. It's also discussed in the [article](https://www.collive.com/show_news.rtx?id=31850) linked in the other [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/99204/9643).

Comment: @Ploni very interesting. My shul is not Chabad and we say that bracha out loud, but I have davened in countless Chabad houses and shuls and they have _always_ said it quietly (along with the brachos _oheiv amo/habocher b'amo yisroel_). It was to the extent that I thought this was a particularly strong Chabad custom.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recording of the nusach for Rosh hashanna and yom kipur from someone who was a chazan (cantor) during the Lubavotcher Rebbe's lifetime. Here is an article about it.... https://www.collive.com/show_news.rtx?id=31850&alias=the-nusach-sung-before-the-rebbe and here it can be purchased... 
https://www.hamafitz.com/tefillos-of-the-days-of-awe.html